# Extract substrings without any spaces from list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

Say I have the following list:

```py
l1 = ['apples', ' bananas' , '  coconuts', '   dates figs guavas', 'lemons ', 'mangoes  ']
```

What would be the best way of extracting each word and discarding the extra spaces?

The result I am after is:

```py
l2 = ['apples', 'bananas', 'coconuts', 'dates', 'figs', 'guavas', 'lemons', 'mangoes']
```

What I've tried so far is:

```py
    clean_l = []

    # Get rid of white spaces 
    for item in l1:
        clean = re.sub("(?m)^\s+", "", item)
        clean_l.append(clean)
```

but this returns the exact same thing as `l1`.

Comment: For one thing your regex explicitly only finds whitespace at the _start_ of a string.

Comment: You might as well use  [`" ".join(l1).split()`](https://ideone.com/Ak6Rp8).

Comment: The easiest with regex might be `re.findall`: `[w for string in l1 for w in re.findall("\w+", string)]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are missing a strip, I guess

Comment: @DaniMesejo Output: `['apples', 'bananas', 'coconuts', 'dates', 'figs', 'guavas', 'lemons', 'mangoes']`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I stand corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
l1 = ['apples', ' bananas' , '  coconuts', '   dates figs guavas', 'lemons ', 'mangoes  ']
res = [ei for e in l1 for ei in e.strip().split()]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['apples', 'bananas', 'coconuts', 'dates', 'figs', 'guavas', 'lemons', 'mangoes']
```

If you insist on using regular expression, although I don't recommend it for this particular problem (see [here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)), use:

```
import re

l1 = ['apples', ' bananas', '  coconuts', '   dates figs guavas', 'lemons ', 'mangoes  ']
res = [ei for e in l1 for ei in re.findall(r"\w+", e)]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['apples', 'bananas', 'coconuts', 'dates', 'figs', 'guavas', 'lemons', 'mangoes']
```

A third alternative (by @WiktorStribiżew) is to use:

```
res = " ".join(l1).split()
```

**Timings**

```
l1 = ['apples', ' bananas', '  coconuts', '   dates figs guavas', 'lemons ', 'mangoes  '] * 1000
import re
%timeit [ei for e in l1 for ei in e.strip().split()]
1.76 ms ± 10.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit " ".join(l1).split()
453 µs ± 3.95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit [ei for e in l1 for ei in re.findall(r"\w+", e)]
7.77 ms ± 59.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Why wasn't the regular expression working?

Comment: @jonrsharpe already commented in the question, but I try to avoid regex when possible